# Implementation of Site-wide arrayController in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have been looking to a solution to this for about a week now with no luck. We have an ember application which has a sidebar that is present on all routes which displays a list of user posts. It is important that the posts update in real-time as they are submitted as well as sort with the newest post at the top of the list, which from what I've read will require an array controller. The problem is, I cant find any way (or rather dont understand) to use an array controller and specific model that is not directly referenced to the current route. I have tried rendering the sidebar with the following code in the application route:

```
Destination.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(model) {

        var self = this;

        return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            new Em.RSVP.hash({

                post : self.store.find('post')

            }).then(function (results) {

                resolve({

                    post: results.post

                });
            });
        });
    },

    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {

        this.render();

        this.render('sidebars/postBar', {

            outlet: 'postbar',

            into: 'application',

            controller: 'posts',

            model: 'post'

        });
    }
```

Then I have the following code for my array controller

```
Destination.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    itemController: 'post',

    sortProperties: ['id'],

    sortAscending: false

});
```

However this doesnt work at all and I'm having trouble finding any examples of how to accomplish this.

Comment: What’s the purpose of `model: 'post'` in your second `render` call? It would be helpful to set up a JSBin or the like.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you can use is to load whatever models you need for the entire application in the ApplicationRoute.  You don't have to create the RSVP.Promise as you have done, simply return an RSVP.all or RSVP.hash as follows:

```
Destination.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(model) {
    return Em.RSVP.Hash({
      post : self.store.find('post')
      //  fetch other models as required
    });
  }
});
```

Now there are two options for the controller setup and rendering.

#### Option 1: Outlets and route based controller setup.

The next thing is to setup the appropriate controller and render the view.  Assuming you have defined an `{{outlet 'sidebar'}}` in your application template, the ApplicationRoute can render the sidebar as follows:

```
Destination.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model, transition) {
    // perform default application controller setup
    this._super(controller, model, transition);
    // setup sidebar controller model
    this.controllerFor('side-bar').set('model', model.posts);
    // setup other controllers as required...
  },

  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    // render `posts` template into `side-bar` outlet with `side-bar` controller.
    var c = this.controllerFor('side-bar');
    this.render('side-bar', { outlet: 'side-bar, controller: c });
    // other top level outlet rendering as required...
  }
});
```

#### Option 2: View helper based controller setup and rendering.

Instead of using additional outlets, we can avoid the need to override `setupController` or `renderTemplate` in the route entirely.  We can use the handlebars `render` helper to specify both the model and controller to use directly from our template.

So given your application controller will be setup with the result of the RSVP hash by default, it will contain a 'posts' property on its model/content. Just add the following to your application template:

```
{{render 'side-bar', posts}}
```

The above will render the `sidebar` template and setup the singleton SideBar controller using the posts model for you.  I think this is cleaner than messing about with outlets given it doesn't sound like you going to be rendering different views into the sidebar based on your question.

API documentation on the render helper is [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render), with an overview of the rendering helpers [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/).

Note I have used Ember-cli resolver naming conventions which use a dasherized naming convention.  If you're not using Ember CLI (which I highly recommend) then you may have to use the PascalCased string names ie 'SideBar' instead of 'side-bar'.